# How to not miss rows during an Insert/Delete

Tags: sql

Have a question.  I have two statements as below:

Statement #1

```
Insert into tblAudit (Col1, Col2)
Select Col1, Col2 From tblSoruce
Where "Same Condition"
```

Statement #2

```
Delete from tblSource
Where "Same Condition"
```

I am trying to first put in an audit table, all the rows that are being deleted later.

What is the best way to accomplish this without "missing" any rows in between the 2 statements?

In the way I have the SQL statements, the number of rows can change from the first to the second statement, which is not what I want.  (I can't use the OUTPUT clause as there are FK relationships)

Any help in how to accomplish this in a more efficient manner (without temp tables)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a trigger to automatically perform the insert into the audit log when the values are deleted from tblSource; this way you know exactly what rows were deleted and should be inserted into tblAudit .

Comment: Sure.  But that means that any deletes to the source table from any application will cause the insert to the audit...Trying to see if I can just do it for this specific sql portion only.

Comment: Could you set a transaction isolation level to assure that the data is consistent? I don't have much experience with most of the levels but a quick search shows REPEATABLE READ might help.

Comment: No problem.  I hope it helps.